# Iterate recursively through current, then parent directory to find a subdirectory

Tags: recursion, boost, siblings, c++03, boost-filesystem

I want to use `boost::filesystem` to find a directory of a certain name.
Start of the search shall be the current directory. If the directory I am looking for does not exist, I need to search the parent directory and so on.
3 directory levels  shall be searched.
However, my code does seem to be stuck in a loop.
Does boost offer a more convenient solution maybe?

```
for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator Itr(boost::filesystem::current_path()); oItr != oEndItr; ++oItr)
{
 if (!boost::filesystem::is_directory(oItr->status()))
        continue;
 if (oItr->path().filename().string() != "DirectoryName")
 {
        if (oItr == oEndItr)
            oItr = boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(oItr->path().parent_path());
        continue;
    }
 //Found the directory!
}
```

Comment: `oItrEnd` is wrong after setting `oItr` to point to the subdirectory. But even if you've updated `oEndItr` when you go deeper, your code needs to track an entire *stack* of `oEndItr` in order to run each nested directory loop to completion. So you could create a stack, or even simpler, a recursive function, which uses "the stack" so you don't have to create your own.

Answer (score 2):

You need a tree recursive algorithm that tracks which directories have already been visited.

You should either canonicalize the paths for this purpose or use a `(device,inode)` combination to check for visited state. This is to avoid looping on (sym)link cycles or different spellings of the same name.

In my simple example:

```
for (fs::path current : { ".", "..", "../..", "../../../" }) {
    auto const& sub = recurse(fs::canonical(current));
    if (!sub.empty())
        return sub;
}
```

It also accounts for the case where e.g. `../..` and `../../../` refer to the same directory (`/`).

Demo output:

```
mkdir -p haystack/{a..z}/sub/{1..10} haystack/j/sub/9/needle
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -o test
cd haystack/k/sub/4 && ../../../../test
FOUND "/tmp/1429002953.62583/haystack/j/sub/9/needle"
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b28bc52144c638cb)</kbd>** or **<kbd>[Live On Coliru (c++03)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd963d67cbda5291)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

fs::path find_directory(std::string const& name) {
    std::set<fs::path> visited;

    std::function<fs::path(fs::path const&)> recurse;
    recurse = [&visited, &name, &recurse](fs::path const& dir) -> fs::path {
        if (visited.insert(dir).second) { // not visited already
            try {
                for (auto& de : boost::make_iterator_range(fs::directory_iterator(dir), {})) {
                    if (fs::is_directory(de))
                    {
                        if (de.path().filename() == name)
                            return de.path();

                        // TODO check accessibility?
                        auto const& sub = recurse(de.path());

                        if (!sub.empty())
                            return sub;
                    }
                }
            } catch(fs::filesystem_error& e) {
                std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        }
        return {};
    };

    for (fs::path current : { ".", "..", "../..", "../../../" }) {
        auto const& sub = recurse(fs::canonical(current));
        if (!sub.empty())
            return sub;
    }

    return {};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "FOUND " << find_directory("needle") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However it appears you are using C++11 code and boost > 1.49. Is that correct? Neither can I use `auto` nor this syntax: `{".",".."}`

Comment: @tzippy I don't think that the fact that you cannot use the features should prevent you from learning how they work, so you can trivially translate to c++03 if need be: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd963d67cbda5291)**. I'll re-tag your question for you now.

Comment: Would have been nice if you'd told us that from the start, @tzippy.

Comment: Sorry for not giving that information. @sehe: Just wanted to point it out. Learning a lot from your answer actually!

Answer (score 1):

To recursively iterate over a directory and subdirectories, Boost.Filesystem provides the iterator boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    path full_path(initial_path<path>());
    full_path = system_complete(path(argv[0]));
    path dir = full_path.parent_path();

    for(recursive_directory_iterator it(dir); it != recursive_directory_iterator() ; it++)
    {
        if (it->path().filename().string() == "DirectoryName")
        {
            std::cout << it->path() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```